# asp.net ImageConversion.aspx webcam is not working in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webcam

I am new to asp.net, I want to use web camera in my application and should take the snap,for that I have used  [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/528929/Capture-images-using-web-camera-in-ASP-NET) source code and it is working when I run the application in localhost,but after hosting the same code on IIS camera is taking the snap but not saving.
Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

> 1. Make an `Image` First then save it to your **Project Directory.**
> 2. You have the right path that your code accessing to that folder.
> 3. Check folder permission also.

Comment: I think on Capture button click ImageConversions.aspx file not loading to save the image

Answer (score 0):

The app pool where your code will be running under in IIS won't have write access to your `c:\` drive by default.